# How to align mat-tab-group label to left

Tags: sass, angular-material, angular6

I'm using angular material in my development I want to left align my tab labels.

```
<mat-tab-group >
  <mat-tab label="Heading 1"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Heading 2"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Heading 3"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

I'm expecting to see the text **Heading 1, Heading 2 and Heading 3** as left aligned.
Is there a way to achieve this?

https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In theory I wouldn't mess with the Angular Material styles too much, but if you really need to have your labels aligned to the left you can do the following (in your component stylesheet):

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-label {
  padding: 0px !important; // adjust this to whatever padding you need
  justify-content: left !important;
}
```

> [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-vzeyte?file=app%2Fapp.component.scss) is a stackblitz showing it in action.

Comment: Thank you for your response but it seems the style isn't overriding the in-built one
I tried placing the css inside the main.css file but the tab isn't affected

Comment: You need to place it in your components CSS file. Check the stackblitz again, I have added a `min-width` to the tabs so you can see it aligns to the left.

Answer (score 4):

As of AUG 2020  you can use built-in property called [**mat-align-tabs**](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#label-alignment)

It needs be used together with `mat-stretch-tabs="false"`.

```
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs="false" mat-align-tabs="start">
  <mat-tab label="First">Content 1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second">Content 2</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third">Content 3</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs="false" mat-align-tabs="center">
  <mat-tab label="First">Content 1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second">Content 2</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third">Content 3</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs="false" mat-align-tabs="end">
  <mat-tab label="First">Content 1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second">Content 2</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third">Content 3</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```